# Passing return values over recursive functions in C

Tags: c, recursion

I was writing a binary search function:

```
int binsearch(int seq[], int start, int end, int key)
{
    int len = end - start + 1;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    if (len <= 0)
        return -1;
    else if (key == seq[mid])
        return mid;
    else if (key < seq[mid])
        binsearch(seq, start, mid - 1, key);
    else
        binsearch(seq, mid + 1, end, key);
}
```

I was not aware that I returned only once in the innermost call. I compiled it with gcc in my laptop, and it worked perfectly.

However, when I compiled that code in a cloud computer using clang, it threw me a warning that the control could reach the end of a non-void function. Then, I put another variable there to pass the return value over recursive calls.

Why did gcc compile it without any warning and yet the function gave the correct output? Is this a kind of compiler optimization? I thought C would not pass the return value automatically over recursive calls.

Comment: Not returning a value in a function declared to return a value leads to *undefined behavior*. Anything could happen, *including* seemingly working.

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is add a `return` keyword before the calls to `binsearch` in the final `else if` and `else`.

Comment: Side note: once you fix your code by adding a `return` preceding each call to `binsearch`, you can get rid of all the `else`s.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The error message otoh is.

Comment: @barakmanos: You are correct, but beware of the discussions about multiple `return` point in a function. Some people take coding standards like MISRA as a religion ...

Comment: @Olaf I think I have made my question clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*; you *must* explicitly `return` a value on all control paths.

A kind compiler will warn you of this; gcc certainly does if you set an appropriate warning level.

I believe that the fix in your case is to write `return` before your `binsearch` calls.

(The only exception to this is `int main(...)` where the compiler must introduce an implicit `return 0;` if it's missing).

Comment: I understand now. I compiled with gcc again by including `-Wall` and indeed it gave me the warning. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler says that these paths of the function

```
else if (key < seq[mid])
    binsearch(seq, start, mid - 1, key);
else
    binsearch(seq, mid + 1, end, key);
```

do not have return statements.

You need at least to write

```
else if (key < seq[mid])
    return binsearch(seq, start, mid - 1, key);
else
    return binsearch(seq, mid + 1, end, key);
```